# Angular-cli CORS settings

Tags: json, angular, http, cors, httprequest

I have backend url `http://docker-users:5500/users?all=true` which returns me list of users. In angular-cli localhost url is: `http://localhost:4200`. I have set proxy.config.json and add it to `ng serve`. Problem is I still get 404 error when I am trying to reach. Where could be my mistake?

proxy.config.json:

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://docker-users:5500",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

service.ts

```
const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json;'});
const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('all', true);
const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, params: params });
const resp = this.http.get('/api/users', options)
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `pathRewrite` option:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://docker-users:5500",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    },
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

Comment: not working. maybe request url must be changed also or something

Comment: You can delete this comment

Comment: Add the option: `"logLevel": "debug"`  to the `proxy.config.json` file to see debugging information